# Why is \graphicspath an undefined control sequence?

Tags: graphics, packages

In trying to debug something else, I encountered the following error in the MWE `gpath-try.tex` below. What's wrong?

```
(./gpath-try.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-06-18>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
...
./gpath-try.tex:3: Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \graphicspath
                 {{graphics/}}
? q
OK, entering \batchmode...

./gpath-try.tex:3: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.3 \graphicspath{{g
                    raphics/}}
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\graphicspath{{graphics/}}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

I thought that had always worked, but I also tried reversing the order, this time using:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{graphics/}}
```

But that also fails, giving error:

```
(./graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2020-06-04 Load graphics packages and defines colors

./graphics.sty:12: Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \graphicspath 
                              
l.12 \graphicspath
                  {{graphics/}} % set graphics path
```

Comment: Naively I'd have said load `\usepackage{graphicx}` *before* you say `\graphicspath{{graphics/}}`. (After all `\graphicspath` does something graphic-y, so it appears natural to load `graphicx` first.)

Comment: Essentially same error if, as I've added to question, I load `graphicx` first!

Comment: It works for me if I load `graphicx` first.

Comment: Even with loading `graphicx` first, still that error, and even if I run `pdflatex` from the command line rather than from within TeXShop!

Comment: What puzzles me about the `.log` you show is that it says `(./graphics.sty`. I'd expect something like `("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty"` or `(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty`. Do you have a local copy of `graphics.sty` in your document folder? Or is one of *your* files called `graphics`?

Comment: @mowwe: mystery solved! I had a file `graphics.sty` that had been a `preamble` subdirectory of my source document's directory, and catastrophically moved it one level up without remembering to change its name. (Stupid error!) Thank you!!!

Comment: `graphics.sty` is the name of a base file of the LaTeX distribution. You probably shouldn't have a file of that name anywhere as it masks the real `graphics.sty`.

Comment: There's a reason why I recommend “packages first”, “settings after”.

Answer (score 3):

The correct loading order is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{graphics/}}

\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

The last `.log` in the question shows

```
(./graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2020-06-04 Load graphics packages and defines colors
```

suggesting that you have a local file called `graphics.sty` that gets loaded instead of – and therefore masks – the LaTeX base file `graphics.sty`, which announces itself as

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2019/11/30 v1.4a Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
```

(on my machine anyway: file path, date and exact version may of course vary).

Of course it is really bad luck here that the command defined by the real `graphics.sty` is used by a local version of `graphics.sty` that is loaded instead of the LaTeX core file. But at least it breaks loudly. Problems with local files masking the system files can be very tricky to debug.

It is always dangerous to use a file name that is already taken by a package/LaTeX base file, but of course it is hard to know all possible 'forbidden' names.